# What is getting checked in isEqual?

Tags: objective-c, uiview

The Apple guide for `isEqual` says:

> Returns a Boolean value that indicates whether the receiver and a
>   given object are equal. (required)
>
> This method defines what it means for instances to be equal. For
>   example, a container object might define two containers as equal if
>   their corresponding objects all respond YES to an `isEqual:` request.
>   See the NSData, NSDictionary, NSArray, and NSString class
>   specifications for examples of the use of this method.
>
> If two objects are equal, they must have the same hash value. This
>   last point is particularly important if you define `isEqual`: in a
>   subclass and intend to put instances of that subclass into a
>   collection. Make sure you also define hash in your subclass.

So my question is if I want to compare two UIButtons or two UILabels (two UIViews) using `isEqual`, and beforehand I have checked if their classes are the same class and then call `isEqual`, what is getting checked? are the properties, values, action messages, target objects are getting checked?

Thanks

Comment: isEqual probably isn't the right option for something as complex as a view. Can you say what are you actually trying to do, rather than how you are currently trying to do it?

Comment: I want to compare if the two view are the same, so i check all the subviews and one by one i want toc heck their properties, e.g. if there are uibuttons and uilabels I want to compare them in this view and the other view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the isEqual: method of NSObject checks whether the hash of the two objects are equal. In practice, the hash is the address of the instance if it isn't overridden. However, on simple data container classes, isEqual is overridden, and, for example, the isEqual: method of NSString invokes isEqualToString: after checking that the object being compared to is an NSString instance. Same applies, as I've mentioned before, to NSData, NSNumber, NSDate, NSArray and NSDictionary. However, UIView (and all its parents) don't override isEqual: as there's no obvious way to decide whether two views are considered equal. You'd better compare another, more significant property of the views to be examined.

Comment: No, the `-isEqual:` method does not check the `-hash`. For one thing, the hash can be the same for unequal objects. The `NSObject` implementation simply compares the object pointers for equality. That is, an object is only equal to itself.

Comment: @KenThomases `-isEqual:` definitely checks the `-hash` (but not only this). That's why Apple states in the documentation that if you choose to override `-isEqual:` you _must_ override `hash` too.

Comment: You have to override `-hash` in order to maintain the relationship between them (different hash implies inequal, equality implies same hash), but that doesn't mean that `-isEqual:` checks the hash. In fact, if it did, then there would be no need to change them both. Just changing one would suffice.

Comment: [Here](http://pastebin.com/nN9npbFJ) is `NSObject`'s implementation of `-isEqual:` from 10.6.8's CoreFoundation (i386). Just compares `self` with the argument. No call to `-hash` or anything else.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/isEqual: <- I suggest reading the docs for whoever downvoted this.

Comment: I downvoted and I explained in three comments. I'm quite familiar with the docs and you're misinterpreting them. Not only do the docs not say that `-isEqual:` checks the hash, but I have shown the actual implementation and that it's not doing so.

Answer (score 0):

No, isEqual does a simple check for the memory address of pointers to see if they are the same object. You'd have to use some other method to check if same the buttons had the same titles but were two separate button instances.

Comment: Not exactly. isEqual is overridden on container classes for a good reason.

Comment: Right but he was asking about it in context of UIbuttons and Uilabels.